# "python" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, pycharm

Для саморазвития начал изучать питон.Скачал его, установил. Далее установил по рекомендациям PyChar. И настал момент реализации своего первого более менее крупного проекта где мне нужен pip, я использую команду python get-pip.py после чего мне кидает вышеупомянутую ошибку. Через командную строку на самой винде всё работает, а в PyChar ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @kami, плохая попытка. Это Windows, здесь нет python3.

Comment: Скриншот нужно убрать и вставить текст ошибки текстом.

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий, при установке Python 3 автоматически устанавливается pip. Попробуйте запустить pip из командной строки Windows. Дополнительно устанавливать его через get-pip.py не нужно.

Comment: Пропишите путь к питону

Comment: @insolor ввел в командную строку , все работает, вы были правы, ну хорошо, но как мне тогда установить дополнительную библиотеку? Я хочу установить SpeechRecognition 3.8.1, а для этого необходимо вводить "pip install SpeechRecognition", и выскакивает та же ошибка, только вместо "python" пишет что "pip" не является внутренней или внешней командой и тп.. в командной строке всё работает, а  PyChar не-а.

Comment: @АртёмЧерницкий, в PyCharm - меню File - Settings, Project: (имя проекта), Project interpreter, справа от списка установленных модулей жмем +, в поиске вводим SpeachRecognition, выбираем найденный модуль, потом внизу жмем Install Package.

Comment: @insolor ё-мае, вы мой герой, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По какой-то причине у вас консоль Pycharm не видит общесистемные переменные окружения. Тут два варианта:

1. Устанавливать пакеты через pip из системного cmd
2. Воспользоваться средствами PyCharm: меню File - Settings, Project: (имя проекта), Project interpreter, справа от списка установленных модулей жмем +, в поиске вводим SpeachRecognition, выбираем найденный модуль, потом внизу жмем Install Package

Второй вариант более предпочтительный, т.к. если вы используете в проекте виртуальное окружение, то модуль установится в него, а при установке через системный cmd модуль установится глобально, и скорее всего не будет виден из виртуального окружения. Если вы в проекте не используете виртуальное окружение, то особой разницы не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно в вашем случае - просто не пользуйтесь кириллицей в наименовании папок в пути проекта, и все будет хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо))))))))